# Kruskal-Wallis multiple testing - correction alpha

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test, bonferroni

I have 10 numeric outcomes in one dataset and I want to use Kruskal-Wallis test to identify an influence via a predictor variable (group variable) and also for each age group.

I am testing for each age group (4 categ.) for each of the 10 variables (10*4=40) and I am wondering if I have to correct my alpha (0.05/40). I get a nonsignificant result that way for each test.

I read  that the Kruskal-Wallis test is a omnibus test and hence I don't have to correct  my alpha for multiple testing? is that right?

Normality is not given: that is why I have to use something nonparametric like Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: In short: as @Limey suggests it is better to be migrated. What you are doing is a Bonferrini correction (which is stated to be conservative). Read about Holm's method or the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure which are less conservative. Good luck.

Comment: You need to use some p-value correction, yes. As suggested, Holm correction might be a good idea. Kruskal-Wallis test is an omnibus test in the sense that it gives you an overall statistic telling you if there are any differences between any of the groups. What makes you need correction is that you are running 10 of those. If you ran 1 and did not look at the pairwise comparisons you wouldn't need corrections.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how many tests you are actually running. My guess is you run 10 KW-tests, each of which compares 4 age groups. That'd be 10 tests, not 40 (in which case applying Bonferroni you've got to divide by 10 not 40), but I may have misunderstood this.